# How wordpress detects a plugin update

Tags: plugins, updates, automatic-updates

I am a wp plugin developer and I'd like to know how WP detects when some plugin has an update? I guess it is ok for these plugins which are already in wordpress.org repository. But how I can implement the same mechanism for these plugins which are stored in my own repository? (Already made some googling, unfortunately can't find any info). Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Every 12+ Hours WordPress automatically goes out and checks if a plugin needs to be updated via the WordPress Repository. There's 3 cron jobs that WordPress runs to check on things:

- `wp_version_check` - Checks for Core Updates
- `wp_update_plugins` - Check for Plugin Updates
- `wp_update_themes` - Checks for Theme Updates

A neat little plugin to view these is [WP Crontrol](https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-crontrol/). Now, WP Crons are not like Server Cronjobs, they run during specific situations when conditions are met ( current_time >= 12 AND ... ). I'm not entirely sure what the conditions are but they seem to be admin-panel requests.

There's an options in the database that holds a lot of this information, each cron has it's own transient if I'm not mistaken, you can search you `wp_options` table for `_site_transient` with a `LIKE%..%` statement to see what you get.

`_site_transient_update_plugins` Option holds information such as last checked timestamp, plugins checked, plugins that need updated ( with an array of things such as package URL, new version, etc. ) which is then used to both get and display information to the user about updating and makes it super easy for a user to simply click update ( as it doesn't need to look for the page it already has the update URL in the database ).

I've [played around with this](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/157577/alter-how-often-wordpress-auto-updates-plugins) for a little bit and still don't have a full grasp on it but hopefully the above gives you an idea of how it works.

As far as having WordPres update plugins for your own private repository, there's a few different flavors of it. WooCommerce has a helper plugin that handles most their updates, there's some code to push updates from Github, [here's an answer](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/180727/wordpress-plugin-from-own-server/180736#180736) that pushed me in the right direction. All in all it's not the easiest / most straight-forward thing to do.